Firebase Storage putFile/putData not working
I'm trying to upload image from my flutter app to firebase storage.
final _avatars = AvatarService();

Future _pickImage(BuildContext context) async{
    final img = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (img == null) return;

    try {
      await _avatars.saveAvatar(_auth.getCurrentUser()!.uid.toString(), File(img.path));

      avatar = await _avatars.getAvatar(_auth.getCurrentUser()!.uid.toString());

      setState(() {
        
      });
    } 
    catch(e){
      showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text(e.toString())
      ));
    }
  }

import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

class AvatarService{

  Future saveAvatar(String uid, File file) async{
    final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
    final imgRef = storageRef.child("$uid.jpg");
    await imgRef.putFile(file);
  }

  Future<Uint8List?> getAvatar(String uid) async{
    final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
    final imageRef = storageRef.child("$uid.jpg");

    Uint8List? avatar;

    try{
      avatar = await imageRef.getData();
    }
    catch(e){
      print(e);
    }

    return avatar;
  }
}

But when I'm uploading my photo my app just crushes and I got no image in firebase storage.
I also tried to upload image this way =>
final _avatars = AvatarService();

Future _pickImage(BuildContext context) async{
    final img = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (img == null) return;

    try {
      await _avatars.saveAvatar(_auth.getCurrentUser()!.uid.toString(), File(img.path).readAsBytes);

      avatar = await _avatars.getAvatar(_auth.getCurrentUser()!.uid.toString());

      setState(() {
        
      });
    } 
    catch(e){
      showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text(e.toString())
      ));
    }
  }

class AvatarService{

  Future saveAvatar(String uid, Uint8List imageBytes) async{
    final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
    final imgRef = storageRef.child("$uid.jpg");
    await imgRef.putData(imageBytes);
  }

  Future<Uint8List?> getAvatar(String uid) async{
    final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
    final imageRef = storageRef.child("$uid.jpg");

    Uint8List? avatar;

    try{
      avatar = await imageRef.getData();
    }
    catch(e){
      print(e);
    }

    return avatar;
  }
}

And also tried to change File(img.path).readAsBytes to img.readAsBytes but both this attemps I got just incorect file of size 32b but not the image I was uploading.
Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

It's recommended to work with File rather than passing bytes data.
And when getting data you can use getDownloadUrl rather than getData
please consider modifying your Avatar code:
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

class AvatarService {
  Future<String?> saveAvatar(String uid, File imageFile) async {
    try {
      final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
      final imageRef = storageRef.child("$uid.jpg");
      await imageRef.putFile(imageFile);
      return await imageRef.getDownloadURL();
    } catch (e) {
      print('ERROR (saveAvatar) = ${e.toString()}');
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<String?> getAvatar(String uid) async {
    try {
      final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
      final imageRef = storageRef.child("$uid.jpg");
      return await imageRef.getDownloadURL();
    } catch (e) {
      print('ERROR (getAvatar) = ${e.toString()}');
      return null;
    }
  }
}

And for the picking method should look like this :
File? pickImage(ImageSource src) async {
    final XFile? pickedImageFile =
        await _picker.pickImage(source: src);

    if (pickedImageFile != null) {
      return File(pickedImageFile.path);
    } else {
      print('ERRRO (pickImage) = No image selected');
    }
  }

Note:

call method pickImage(ImageSource.gallery) if you want to pick from gallery.

call method pickImage(ImageSource.camera) if you want to pick from the camera.



Hi, thanks for advices but my problem is in uploading file to firebase storage not in downloading from it. As I wrotted earlier when I'm trying 'putFile' my app just crashing. When I'm trying 'putData' I got incorect file in my firebase storage.

Hello Thank, you for your fast reply,
Could you give me more details about the error message you get?
Are you running this on IOS emulator, Android, the web?
Have you configured right your firebase storage package?.
all this details help me to define the right solution for you.
thank you

I'm running on Windows. in debug console I have this message "Lost connection to device.
Exited."

I think the problem is related to the image_picker platform limitation
consider using file_selector for picking files from windows platform

No I tested image_picker without uploading images to firebase storage and it was working without any problems. The problem is exactly in firebase storage uploading. Image picking and downloading from firebase storage working correctly.

It will rest only one possiblity to check it may fix your problem :
have you configured firebase storage access rules ?
if yes than open a issue in github issues.

Here is my firebase storage rules : "rules_version = '2';
// Craft rules based on data in your Firestore database
// allow write: if firestore.get(
//    /databases/(default)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin;
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
match /{allPaths=**} {
allow read, write: if true;
}
}
}"

$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin what you mean by this condition

here's a version that check a user if it is an admin from users collection
`rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
// Match all paths in the storage bucket
match /{allPaths=**} {
// Allow read access only for authenticated users
allow read: if request.auth != null;
  // Allow write access if the user is an admin
  allow write: if request.auth != null && 
               firestore.get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin == true;
}

}
}`

I changed putFile to putData and runned on Android, everything was working properly. But on Windows I'm getting incorect file and this error in my debug console: [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(1038)] The 'plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage/taskEvent/4afa2f46-62f9-44d4-a040-0084dc0a5740' channel sent a message from native to Flutter on a non-platform thread. Platform channel messages must be sent on the platform thread. Failure to do so may result in data loss or crashes, and must be fixed in the plugin or application code creating that channel.
